# Retrofit2: Adding Token Params(@Query) in Retrofit POST Request

Tags: java, android, android-studio, httprequest, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit2 for a mobile app. The API I'm interacting with requires the Token to be put in the params inorder to get make a valid request. Like this:
[image]

I want to make a POST request wherein I can integrate that token into the params.

[image]

I tried using @Query with no luck, and the Retrofit documentation only demonstrates it in the @GET request. Any idea on how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was just an error in my input. This works. @Query directly in the POST Request puts my passed token directly into the params just fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to add path value dynamically use `@Path`

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("users/{token}")
Call<AgentResponse> agentCreateUse(
        @Path("token") String token);
...
        )
```

And remove `@Query`

- form-urlencoded: POST
- query parameter: GET

Use form-urlencoded requests to send data to a server or API. The data is sent within the request body and not as an url parameter.

Query parameters are used when requesting data from an API or server using specific fields or filter.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Field instead of @Query in the POST request